# Composing RetrieveMultiple query with FetchXML condition

Tags: javascript, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using new OrganizationService endpoint in `MS CRM 2011` — `/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc`.

It seems to it does not support old `Fetch` command. And as I find out I still could use `fetchXML` query by passing it to `RetrieveMultiple` method.

In C# it does look simple:

```cs
string expression = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
<entity name='systemuser'>
<attribute name='businessunitid' />
<attribute name='systemuserid' />
<order attribute='businessunitid' descending='false' />
<filter type='and'>
<condition attribute='systemuserid' operator='eq-userid' />
</filter>
<link-entity name='businessunit' from='businessunitid' to='businessunitid' alias='ah'>
<attribute name='name' />
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>";

FetchExpression fetch = new FetchExpression(expression);
// let's assume GetOrganisationService will return correct instance of IOrganizationService
IOrganizationService service = GetOrganisationService();
EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(fetch);
```

But I need to perform the same thing from JavaScript. And I'm not quite sure how it's possible to compose correct query in this case.

Obviously, that `fetchXML` need to be transformed into `SOAP` in some kind of way, but I brushed all over Internet and SDK and cannot find the way how to do it.

How could I put this kind of request:

```cs
<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
<entity name='systemuser'>
<attribute name='businessunitid' />
<attribute name='systemuserid' />
<order attribute='businessunitid' descending='false' />
<filter type='and'>
<condition attribute='systemuserid' operator='eq-userid' />
</filter>
<link-entity name='businessunit' from='businessunitid' to='businessunitid' alias='ah'>
<attribute name='name' />
</link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>
```

Inside following `SOAP` message?

```xml
<soap:Body>
<RetrieveMultiple xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>
<query xmlns:q1='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query' xsi:type='q1:QueryExpression'>

Some magic here

</RetrieveMultiple>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code required to set c[all the SOAP Retrieve multiple via SOAP from JavaScript](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmsoftwareblog/archive/2011/07/10/using-the-fetchxml-crm-2011-service-within-a-javascript-web-resource.aspx#.UVM-vhyfjIc) is rather verbose.

Your query is simple enough... Any reason you don't use the OData rest call?

Comment: Hm, you're right I haven't thought about this! I could use `REST` endpoint. However I would choose `JSON` response instead of `OData`.

Comment: @shytikov OData will return the results as JSON.  OData is the "querying" language used.

Comment: you're right, sorry, I thought that `OData` is that ugly XML they sending back.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to build something like that by hand; there are third party libraries like [XrmServiceToolkit](http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/) that can handle all the SOAP stuff and only require you to provide the actual FetchXml. The result will be returned resolved to JavaScript objects already.

Comment: I don't like an idea using more third-party libraries than I'm using now, but I will check it. Thank you!